# Create a differential equation and solve for an initial value

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Water flows continuously at the rate of 1 liter per hour into a bucket, but flows out continuously at the rate of 5% of the total amount per hour. Let $W(t)$ be the number of liters in the bucket at time $t$. Solve for $W(t)=0$

We begin by determining the first-order differential equation that models this scenario.

Strategy: (net rate of W) = (rate of flow in) - (rate of flow out).
$$\frac {dW}{dt}=1-0.05W$$

This differential equation is both separable and linear; using separability gives:
$$\int\frac {dW}{1-0.05W}=\int dt$$
$$\int\frac {dW}{1-\frac {W}{20}}=\int dt$$
Let $u={1-\frac {W}{20}}$

then $du =-20dW$ and $\frac {du}{20} = dW$

So: $$-20\ln|W-20|=t+C$$
And solving is a matter of simplification.

However, can this differential equation be solved using an integration factor rather than through use of separability? If so, what does it look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your equation has the following form

$$W'=1-aW$$ When $a=0.05$. So
$$ (W'(t)+aW(t))e^{at}=e^{at}$$
$$\dfrac{d}{dt} \left(  W(t)e^{at} \right)=e^{at}$$

$$ W(t)e^{at}= \frac{1}{a}e^{at}+c$$
$$ W(t)= ce^{-at} +\frac{1}{a}$$

Answer (score 1):

You can also handle this as a linear equation with constant coefficients.

The general solution of the homogeneous equation

$$W'+aW=0$$

is

$$W=Ce^{-at}$$

as the single root of the characteristic equation is $-a$.

Now a particular solution of the non-homogeneous equation is a constant

$$W=\frac1a,$$ as this corresponds to $W'=0$.

Combining both,

$$W(t)=\frac1a+Ce^{-at}$$ and $$C=W_0-\frac1a.$$

Finally,

$$W(t)=0=\frac1a+\left(W_0-\frac1a\right)e^{-at}$$

for $$t=-\frac1a\log(1-aW_0).$$

Notice that a solution only exists when $aW_0<1$.